# Generative design - algorithms and sources

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, references, experiment-design, generative-models

I have recently encountered the term "generative design" where a computer algorithm (usually with the help of Machine Learning) comes up with new designs that conform to a certain set of requirements. These designs are usually more intricate while also being lighter and stronger than what humans would design.

I would like to get deeper into the topic, however I can mostly only find offerings (from AutoDesk etc.) instead of a good description on how exactly it works (or even a mathematical description). Could you please point me to some studies, articles or any sources where I could delve into the topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often called *algorithmic design* or *optimal design*. The last name hints on some optimality criteria, and there are many to choose from! Much used is D-optimality. Some related posts here is [Motivations for experiment design in statistical learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422186/motivations-for-experiment-design-in-statistical-learning/422518#422518)  and  [Is DoE applicable to collect data for machine learning model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401239/is-doe-applicable-to-collect-data-for-machine-learning-model/403370#403370), look at the links and references in there.

There are many published books on the topic, one place to start could be [Optimal Experimental Design with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439816972).  [Bayesian ideas](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~gwoodwor/AdvancedDesign/Chaloner%20Verdinelli.pdf)  could also be useful. [This stored search](https://www.google.com/search?q=algorithmic+experimental+design&oq=algorithmic+experimental+design&aqs=chrome..69i57.10000j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) might be useful.

Alternatively, if your question is more about product design, you could try to ask at https://or.stackexchange.com/.     [Links/papers about machine learning and generative design](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ACYBGNTt5TrKFVqtTkI6VdybsmtPbRQS_w%3A1579888690061&ei=MjArXtmyA4HA5OUPuradkAQ&q=generative+design+and+machine+learning+&oq=generative+design+and+machine+learning+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l2.79053.85981..86914...0.2..0.338.5091.2-21j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0j0i203.7oqD3hyeHcU&ved=0ahUKEwjZk5-B6JznAhUBILkGHTpbB0IQ4dUDCAo&uact=5).